# CSS never loads. Impossible to edit my site. Cache?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, caching

Someone please explain this to me. I'm going crazy. I have a wordpress site and i can never make changes and simply see them in a browser.

So i get that i have to clear all caches etc etc etc. I do so and here are the scenarios:

a) i have w3 cache installed and then my website loads with no css.

b) i disable w3 cache but my website shows up with old css changes. I've added a whole bunch of .xxxxxxx { padding-right: xxpx;} things and they don't appear. But it is only the current changes that i'm in putting that are not showing up. i have a whole bunch of edits taht are showing up. So it must be some kind of cache!!!!@#!@#!@#

I'm going nuts here. About to throw my computer out the window. Is there a way to just disable all caching or something of this nature until i'm done editing the website.

nhchat.com

Answer (score 0):

I think your theme doesn't have support for w3 total cache. Just go into minification and select minification only (dont use "combine"). If the theme isn't built properly then it overrides the order that the files are loaded in.  Secondly make sure that you edit the actual files (that are inside your theme directory) and not the cached ones.

Another thing to look into is the file permissions, right now the files cannot be accessed on your server. So make sure when you goto the address of your cached files, you should see a minified version of the files (right click > view source)

```
http://nhchat.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/dZFNjsIwDIUvRAisuMTsOEBkHNPxTH6q2FD19uO2g0pVsYvf--xnOWffCJIjUVByiUW5dG7SdCzghj55ECEVjyL-3mpRKvFw9l8wUrsmjtT81Mw4E2mSZZYNQsMB1d1ry-7iuWB6RFpmiY6J5HDyt8axo6VeyznO2h0MJDXvhWPmssUpUQcGsMX-z99DS-w3ke69DBhWf-sNdPtl_WjPeoh2s8y4tRpJbwvx89M2r7awkna7HwlYc1_FDvz2BW_ydhQ-RGsO9vwD.css
```